# Identify X server machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, x11-forwarding

Assume we are in a remote bash session with working X forwarding (ssh -X someone@remote or ssh -Y someone@remote).
I wonder if there would be a scriptable way to identify the machine on which the X server is running on by using standard tools (should work on most default posix installions).

I have a bash script which needs to know if its running on the same machine as the X server that will get connected by every X client using $DISPLAY...

Parsing $DISPLAY is not sufficient. Doing "ssh -Y user@localhost" contains "localhost:10" and doing "ssh -Y user@remote.machine" $DISPLAY contains "localhost:10".

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it must be something like a X client - something like "xprop" or "xrandr" that communicates with the X server and asks him for his hostname. "xprop -root" gives me everything i never thought of (desktop names, window titles, color definitions and so on) but NOT the hostname of the machine the Xserver runs on....

Answer (score -1):

The bash variable `$HOSTNAME` may be suitable.

Comment: $HOSTNAME contains the hostname belonging to the bash script... This is the easy part... should be the same as invoking 'hostname -s'. But I need the name of the X server... This could be totally differnt....
e.g.  There are 3 machines (A,B,C). I'm sitting in front of machine A starring to the screen. I have a terminal running a bash. Now I do "ssh -X crazzi@B". Now my $HOSTNAME and 'hostname -s' tell me that I'm on machine B. As X11FORWARDING is enable, my $DISPLAY look s like "localhost:10". But my X server is still on machine A. I know this - but how can i figure it out in my script...?